# Does universal wave function exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology

Does universal wave function exist?

What the science tells us?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're being downvoted, because it's actually a good question (perhaps a little short, but nevertheless important).  A wavefunction is inherently multi-particle.  I had a professor once who got this wrong and said that the single-particle wavefunction was more fundamental, but in reality, effects such as quantum entanglement can only be explained by multi-particle wavefunctions.  These also account for electron-electron correlation, something that is left out of many quantum chemistry calculations at the expense of accuracy.

Comment: "A wavefunction is inherently multiparticle" is certainly not a correct statement. Only in relativistic theory, when the particle number is not fixed, would this be true. Hilbert space isomorphisms aside, what "the wavefunction" represents is very different for different physical systems. It is a solution to a differential equation; the differential equation contains the physics, and is the fundamental concept.

Comment: Huh?  If I have a wavefunction for helium, it needs to be a function of 2 electrons and 2 protons.  Ψ ≠ ψ(x1)ψ(x2)ψ(x3)ψ(x4); you can't separate it like that.

Comment: @Nick we seem to have people lurking in the background who downvote capriciously and without comment for no good (physics) reason these days ...Obviously one has to live with this ...

Comment: @Nick I'd hazard a guess that it's being downvoted because it's not really clear. Anixx, could you elaborate your question? It's rather broad/unclear at the moment.

Comment: @Manishearth I dont see what is too broad or unclear about the question. It is only written in a very minimalistic way, and of course it would be better if Annix could say a bit more. But in my opinion there is no reason to down/close vote or something ...

Comment: @Dilaton: Nobody has close voted (there was a flag though). And I haven't voted at all here. Regarding the voting, that's _your_ opinion. You can ask why a post got downvoted, but once you find out you probably shouldn't complain about it, since it'll get you nowhere (instead, use the information to make the post better when the post in question is yours).

Comment: @Manishearth Your guess about the reason for the downvotes here and their legitimacy is just your personal opinion. A better and more constructive way to say that a post should be improved is to leave a corresponding comment instead of a downvote without stating a reason for it. And I am certainly not the only one who has noted that there are in fact people on the site who capriciously downvote for no physics reasons. Encouraging such behavior does not improve (the atmosphere of) the site...

Comment: @Dilaton: Yes, it's my opinion. So? And I did mention to Anixx that he should elaborate. There is nothing such as an "illegitimate" downvote. It's the downvoter's business why they downvote, and it's not that big a deal in the end as long as the question is net positive. And _you don't know why they downvoted, so don't say that it's for "no physics reason"_. I'm not encouraging this, but I'm not going to take action against it either.

Answer (score 6):

Wavefunctions live on *configuration spaces*.  A configuration space is (not surprisingly) the space of configurations of the system in question.  In elementary quantum mechanics with several particles, it's the space of configurations of those particles.

In a more field theoretic scenario, the [functional Schroedinger picture](http://www.thetangentbundle.net/wiki/Quantum_field_theory/free_scalar_field/functional_Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture), you have wavefunctions (strictly wavefunction *als*) on the configuration space of classical fields.

So the meaning of a wavefunction depends on the elements in your model (particles in QM, classical fields in field theory).  I guess by "universal wavefunction" you mean a wavefunction which describes everything in the universe?  If the principles of quantum mechanics are correct and universal, then once you have identified the ingredients of a theory of everything, then there will be a wavefunction to describe its quantum mechanical states.

A note of caution:  when you hear people (e.g. Hartle and Hawking) refer to "the wave function of the universe", they're not referring to this ultimate entity, but rather to a wavefunction which describes the large scale structure of a highly symmetric model of the universe.  Their configuration space is [minisuperspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minisuperspace), and their wavefunction usually refers to just the allowed values of a single parameter!

Comment: Reading the question, I immediadely thought about the Hartle-Hawking wave function :-). Maybe you can extend this point a bit? However, I already like and +1ed your answer.

Comment: @Dilaton  I got the slight impression that Anixx was asking about something more general than the HH wavefunction, so I kept it very general.  A description of the HH argument would be a different question, and it may already exist here somewhere (?)

Comment: I have just searched for hartle-hawking, but there seems to be no question directly asking for a more general description of it ...